# Why must "this.x = x" be used when "return x" is allowed?

Tags: java, syntax

I have a little misunderstanding with a tutorial. Here is a cut from it:

```
public class Test {
  private int id;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Anyway the thing i cant understand is how to refer to id. For example i can see that in getId method i can directly acces previously defined id by just saying return id. But in setId method previously defined id is refered to as this.id and method parameter is id.

Now if there would be "return this.id" in get method then i would understand everything. But at the moment i am confuzed. I assume that if i would return id in set method i would get the parameter back, not the class defined id.
So in conclusion, class defined id can be acceced by just typing "id" unless there is a parameter passed with the same name? That sounds kind of strange, what am i missing?

Comment: `So in conclusion, class defined id can be acceced by just typing "id" unless there is a parameter passed with the same name? That sounds kind of strange, what am i missing?` Actually sounds to me like you understand it already. The second `id` doesn't have to be a parameter though, it can be a local variable as well. (declared as `int id;` within the setId-method.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, in normal conditions the `this` inside of a class is optional. any attribute can be refered with or without the `this`.

When you have a parameter or a local variable with the same name, the ambiguity makes writing the `this`, compulsory.

This is called "*shadowing*". It is said that the local variable is shadowing the attribute.

When you write `id`, the most reasonable guess for Java is that you mean the most local reference, which is the parameter name rather than the attribute. To override this behavior, you have to clarify that you are willing to access `this.id`, meaning the attribute, not the local variable.

Hope that cleared things out!

Answer (score 3):

```
this.id = id;
```

The problem is you also have a local variable of the same name. Because of this, you cannot access the class member directly, since `id` will refer to the local variable. This is why `this` is needed to access the class member variable here.

You can rewrite as below, by changing the name, and now `this` is not needed again.

```
public void setId(int locID) {
    id = locID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this.id in the getId method and it will still work.  It's saying the same thing, actually. This will compile and is perfectly valid:

```
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: When you say "Someone else" it sounds like it could mean `another object` (or "another pet owner"), although you are correct about using `this.id`. However, just to make things even worse, if there would be a method with a parameter `Test anotherTest` you could use `anotherTest.id` directly, without having to use the getter. (And there is your "Someone else"-object -- in which case simply using "id" would mean "this.id", unless a *local variable/parameter* of that name exists.)

Comment: Yeah I suppose you're right.  I'll cut out the second part of my answer

Answer (score -3):

If you have created object from Test class and you trying to access that `id` 
like this:

```
int test;
test=TestObject.id;
```

You will get error because `id` is private so you must say

```
test=TestObject.getid();
```

Now `getid()` will return for us the private `id` we can call it because its public method

Comment: This is not what the question is about.